# ZeroBrane remote debugging

Tags: lua, zerobrane

I used ZeroBrane on Windows to remote debug my program on linux.
My program invoke lua from c++.
But the breakpoint cannot be hit.

ZeroBrane output as below:

```
Debugger server started at AGOC3-706:8172.
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): basedir D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\
New base directory is D:/WorkSpace/sichuan/branches/v1.0.1-2017-07-12/lua/
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): nil nil nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): delallb
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): nil nil nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 1
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  1   nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 37
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  37  nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 305
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  305 nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 831
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  831 nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 1718
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  1718    nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 3441
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  3441    nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): load D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): lua/hall2/main.lua  2   nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): basedir D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\    lua/
New base directory is D:/WorkSpace/sichuan/branches/v1.0.1-2017-07-12/lua/
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): nil nil nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): delallb
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): nil nil nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 1
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  1   nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 37
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  37  nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 305
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  305 nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 831
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  831 nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 1718
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  1718    nil
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): setb D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\hall2\hall.lua 3441
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger received (file, line, err): hall2/hall.lua  3441    nil
Mapped remote request for 'lua/' to 'D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\'.
Debugging session started in 'D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\'.
[192.168.88.238:47444] Debugger sent (command): run
```

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say why it may be not working without having more details about your setup (version of the IDE, version of the debugger you use remotely, the directory you start the debugger in on Linux), but some of the reasons why breakpoints may not be triggered are [listed in the FAQ](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-faq#why-breakpoints-are-not-triggered). If you are not using the latest release of the IDE (v1.60), I'd try with it and would also make sure that the debugger (mobdebug.lua) you use remotely comes from that release as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. ZeroBrane version is 1.60; mobdebug is 0.648 and the zerobrane on linux is also the latest from the offical site. I compare mobdebug.lua of windows and linux It is identical. Is there some impact since my program is multi-thread and I just add require('mobdebug').start("192.168.88.180") to one of them.



I add the absolute path to function "luaL_dofile" but it still not work. Log as:


Mapped remote request for '/home/pomato/scb/lua/' to 'D:\WorkSpace\sichuan\branches\v1.0.1-2017-07-12\lua\'.

Comment: You may want to [check on this thread](https://www.freelists.org/post/zerobrane/Remote-debugging-IDE-project-path-vs-actual-file-path,5) that covers a somewhat similar situation and may provide more detailed explanation as to how the debugger works with mapping cross-platform paths. You may want to send me an email to the address on the project website as it may be easier to get more details that way.